# ReactJS - Search/Iterate through array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an object like that:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "is_deleted": false,
      "name": "Sarah"
    },
    {
      "id": "3520",
      "is_deleted": true,
      "name": "Bobby"
    },
    {
      "id": "3520",
      "is_deleted": true,
      "name": "Sartah"
    }
  ]
}
```

React code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input } from 'antd';
import { connect } from 'dva';

const Search = Input.Search;

@connect(({ rule, loading }) => ({
  rule,
  loading: loading.models.rule,
}))

export default class SearchBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isListLoaded: false,
            resultArr: {}
        }
    }

    performSearch(value) {
    for( var i = this.props.rule.data.list.length; i--; ) {
        for (var key in this.props.rule.data.list[i]) {
            this.setState({resultArr: this.state.resultArr.push(i)});
            }
    }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (!this.state.isListLoaded) {
            const { dispatch } = this.props;
            dispatch({
                type: 'rule/fetch'
            });
            this.setState({ isListLoaded: true });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
           <Search
            placeholder="Search..."
                    onChange={(event) => this.performSearch(event.target.value)}
            style={{ width: "250px", "margin-left": "20px"}}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

> My goal is very simple: I want to search through this object, and
>   return the entire array(s) that contains the keyword.

Example: if I search "Sar", I should get 2 objects:

```
{
  "id": "1234",
  "is_deleted": false,
  "name": "Sarah"
},
{
  "id": "3520",
  "is_deleted": true,
  "name": "Sartah"
}
```

Problem is, I get an error when I'm trying this code. I did search for previous solutions to this problem here on SO, but I can only find examples where there's only one element returned. What I want, is to get **ALL** the results that contain the keyword in **ANY** attributes (in this example, I'm returning 2 elements, not just one)

Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```js
const { data } = {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "is_deleted": false,
      "name": "Sarah"
    },
    {
      "id": "3520",
      "is_deleted": true,
      "name": "Bobby"
    },
    {
      "id": "3520",
      "is_deleted": true,
      "name": "Sartah"
    }
  ]
};

const keyword = "Sar";

const filtered = data.filter(entry => Object.values(entry).some(val => typeof val === "string" && val.includes(keyword)));

console.log(filtered);
```

It filters the `entries` of data Array with the following criterium: at least one of the entry's values must contain a given keyword.

Since IE doesn't yet support [`Object.values()`](https://caniuse.com/#search=Object.values) and [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://caniuse.com/#search=string.includes) you can use the following:

```
const containsKeyword = val => typeof val === "string" && val.indexOf(keyword) !== -1;

const filtered = data.filter(entry => Object.keys(entry).map(key => entry[key]).some(containsKeyword));
```

or polyfill these ES6 features, see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756211/best-way-to-polyfill-es6-features-in-react-app-that-uses-create-react-app).

To make the `keyword` lookup case insensitive, you can use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/RegExp):

```
const re = new RegExp(keyword, 'i');
const filtered = data.filter(entry => Object.values(entry).some(val => typeof val === "string" && val.match(re)));
```

Comment: Note that `Object.values` and `String.includes` are not supported in IE.

Comment: any idea on how to make it case insensitive?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through array simply use filter method of javascript

```
   performSearch(value) {
   const unfilteredData = this.props.rule.data.list;
   const filteredDate = unfilteredData.filter((val) => {
     return val.name.indexOf(val) !== -1;
   });
   this.setState({
      resultArr: filteredDate,
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
performSearch(value) {
    let filteredData = this.props.rule.data.list.filter(item => {
        let isFiltered = false;
        for(let key in item){
            if(item[key].includes(value)){
                isFiltered = true;
            }
        }
        return isFiltered;
    })
    this.setState({resultArr: filteredData});
}
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation with  your code so that the asker (and future readers) know why there was the problem, as well as know how to fix it.

Comment: `if(item[key].includes` will throw for non-strings.