# React app is not working on IE 7 and 8 after using react-app-polyfill but working for IE 9 and above

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, build, version

I have react application trying to run the app in IE by default the version of IE is 7 where it is not working however it is working IE 9 and above by followed the steps fron the question below

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756211/best-way-to-polyfill-es6-features-in-react-app-that-uses-create-react-app
```

but the app is not wokring in IE7 and IE9

Tried to do  following in the src/index.js

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie7';
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie8';
```

which says module not found

Please say is there a way to show the application in IE7 and IE9

Comment: ReactJS do not supports the IE 7 and IE 8 version. If you think that the below suggestion can answer your question then you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ReactJS can only work with the IE 9, IE 10 and IE 11 versions. To support the IE 9, IE 10 and IE 11 you need to add polyfills. IE versions older then IE 9 are not supported.

So it looks like you cannot run the ReactJS app on the IE 7 or IE 8 browser. The IE 7 and IE 8 are too old versions and out of support scope of the Microsoft. I suggest you to use the latest Microsoft browser to avoid such kind of issues. If you are not able to move to the latest Microsoft browser then at least try to use the IE 11 browser.

[image]

References:

1. [Supported Browsers](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/#supported-browsers)
2. [react-app-polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md#react-app-polyfill)