# how to get a file without requiring in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tons of files where I have to add this function.

```js
const Media  = require("../../functions/Media");
Media(....);
```

Is there any way to:

> Directly add **Media()** function without requiring the file

Comment: You could copy and paste the file contents.

Comment: @Barmar I mean is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: You can do this in your main file: `global.Media = require(..)` then it will be available in every file like this `Media(....);`

Comment: @Molda id doesnt work

Comment: Did you put it in the main file that is the starting point of your application?

Comment: @codejockie yes.
I added it into the file that starts first & from where all other files are executed

Comment: You could try creating a function and exporting it, then import/require it where ever you want it.

Comment: @codejockie didn't get what you said

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the framework you are using. You need to find the starting index file and append all global functions there. Samples are given below.

```
// Override Globals in Backend Nodejs

if (typeof global !== "undefined") {
  global.someGlobalFunction = function () {};
}
// Override Globals in Frontend Nodejs/reactjs
// Override Globals in Frontend javascript written on nodejs

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  window.someGlobalFunction = function () {};
}
```

**Node.js + Express (Backend)**

Look for file define server, `app.listen`, Defined on top before import other modules

**Node.js + React (Frontend)**

Look for file define `react.render`, `app.jsx`, Defined on top before import other modules

**Learn the concept of polyfill:**

[Best way to polyfill ES6 features in React app that uses create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756211/best-way-to-polyfill-es6-features-in-react-app-that-uses-create-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring it as global in index file:

```
const {Media} = require('./functions/Media');

global.MediaGlobal = function Media(input) {
   Media(input)
}
```

Comment: `global.Media = require('./functions/Media');`
I did this in my index.js
But its showing error: `Media is not defined`

Comment: Check my updated answer